# Set BuildAction in Visual Studio from pre build event

Tags: android, visual-studio, build, android-assets, build-events

I have droid and `iOS` `xamarin` projects plus a shared library.  Both apps use a common set of images.  For android these should live in the `Assets` folder.  I have a pre build event that copied them from the shared project to the android project.

```
xcopy /E /Y "$(SolutionDir)VentureLibrary\Art\RogueLife\*" "$(ProjectDir)Assets"
```

That works fine but that doesn't seem to be the same as adding the files manually.  Then they get their build action set to `AndroidAsset`.

So my question is, can you set a build action for a file in a pre build event?  If not, is there another way of achieving the same result?